# How to handle character encoding in spring RestController

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-boot, character-encoding

I'm trying to find some information on how I should handle character encoding in my `RestController`.

Spring seems to completely ignore the charset sent in the `Content-Type` header. No matter which charset is sent to the server using this header, the server tries to read it as UTF-8 and sends response with charset UTF-8.

Here is a GitHub repository with a demo reproducing this scenario: https://github.com/hawk1234/characterEncodingTest

Can someone point me where is it described in spring documentation? I came across Content Negotiation but I think it is more about response format rather then encoding.

**UPDATE 2018-11-01**

I've implemented some tests to better show what is the problem. Commit **86dc434351d7ee2c142afc8f389e7837810b19f6** includes class `EncodingTest` which tests endpoint using different encodings.

I've also implemented my encoding handling (Commit **a26c5da0b25fba8a40e3be41e967e6b1e5c4d546**) however it is very basic implementation and may not take all scenarios into account. I'm still looking for easier solution using existing libraries.

Comment: The current JSON RFC requires UTF-8. Would you rather a 400 or [406](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406) over ignoring the charset? (I'm not a Spring user so I can't respond in that context.) Why would you want to not use UTF-8 anyway?

Comment: @TomBlodget once you use any non-english character, UTF-8 becomes obstruction. UTF-16 might be better in that regard, but there are specific situations which just can't be handled by UTF.

Answer (score 0):

By default charset is UTF-8, **MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter** is who manages the charSet. You can override by implementing the bean and setting charSet to null.

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    jsonConverter.setDefaultCharset(null);
    return jsonConverter;
}
```

I created a pull request with these changes on your repository [pullRequestCharacterEncoding](https://github.com/hawk1234/characterEncodingTest/pull/1) and works well.
Kind regards.

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution does not seem to work. I've added tests that check the endpoint for different encodings (Commit 86dc434351d7ee2c142afc8f389e7837810b19f6)

Comment: I wanna get my bounty xD

Comment: @JonathanJohx: I also think that Jackson is component that is in charge of handling the encoding. However, to the best of my knowledge, Jackson only supports Unicode encodings (UTF-8, UTF-16 etc.). In order the have it read other encodings, you need to override much more code and initialize it with a `Reader` instance so it doesn't do anything with the encoding anymore.

Comment: If you add the reference for this statement `By default charset is UTF-8`, i will upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following in your request:

```
Accept-Charset: <US-ASCII or any charset you want to set>
```

Please check the below link for more details:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Charset

Please let me know if it works for you